# Self organizing layouts

Tags: jquery, html, css

Quite a while ago i was more in websites building then i am now.
In my time there where huge debates about what to use; tables or pure CSS alternatives.
I went out of the webdesigning, but now an old question re-surfaces.

What i would like to create is a web page design that depending on screensize, would self organize the page into columns, so that for example on a PDA it would show 1 column
On an old computer monitor, it would show 2 colomns, and on a widescreen laptop it would show 3 columns. I forgot how this was called and how it was done in the past, it had to do with XML and storing data seperate from design (if i remember well), perhaps these days better methods exist to do that, **does this, anyone ring this a bell ?**

Also i note a lot is possible with Jquery and and brouwser depending webkits. 
But i need to make sure that it would run on all (modern) brouwsers : Iexplorer, Firefox, chrome
And Jquery is nice too, but i am kinda woried that some day one of these brouwser vendors decides that jscript like java isnt enabled by default (or is that very unlikely ?)11

Perhaps someone can point me to a method that is the prefered way to do this.

Comment: Use [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: First thing to note is that JQuery is just a JavaScript library and as such it is highly unlikely that one of the major browser vendors will disable JS by default.

Comment: Try out bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS mediaqueries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) or you can use a framework therefore (like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/))

What I found lately is [intention.js](http://intentionjs.com/) which works a bit diffrent (it will manipulate the HTML source according to the given rules)

Comment: You certainly have experience with al lot of them, which one would you choose if you where a bit short on time to learn and understand it? I need to create a small website (besides my other work), not something huge with many pages.

Comment: I would go with Bootstrap, because I know it. I never worked with intention.js but it looks promising.

Comment: Hm i also got that idea from intent that it looks easy, in some sense but in other senses it seams unclear.

Comment: just found a helpfull link for people having the same questions as i did http://cssmatter.com/blog/intentionjs/

Answer (score 0):

I would say that JavaScript is unlikely to be switched off by default, but you should always have an alternative.

Here is a decent library I've used in the past use for multiple column layouts and it works pretty well on desktop/mobile/tablet formats. http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/